# How to prevent Chrome from hiding video controller when using overflow: auto;?

Tags: css, google-chrome, video, controller, overflow

I'm aware there had been a fairly recent update that removed the video controller from Chrome and that this feature has been added back in the latest versions. However, I'm having an issue with Chrome removing the video controls from videos that are in div blocks that use overflow: auto; to scroll the content. I'm unable to find any documentation of this issue and I'm wondering if there is a possible workaround for this.